# Will my laptop memory stick (RAM) be still usable if its kept out for an extended period of time?

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron

I have a dell inspiron 3558 laptop and an extra DDR3L physical memory stick which has been lying around for quite a long time (Probably a year or so) that was removed from another system (An all-in-one pc) Will that ram be still usable? I cannot see any physical damage on it and it still seems usable. If not, then can it harm my laptop in any way if I try installing it?
Also what are the ways of cleaning such a memory stick, like using an eraser or something?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible it will work, depending on the environment it was stored in, and if it was exposed to electrostatic.

The risk of it damaging your computer is low - as recommended, throw it into the computer and run a burn in test at least overnight (preferably longer) - if it burns in OK you are all set to go. If it fails the test, don't use it for anything serious as it will cause instability and possibly data corruption.

As an aside - If you are not a hacker, don't use corrosive cleaners like vinegar, if you are a hacker, make sure to neutralise it afterwards. Similarly, blowing air (I use an air compressor on my older gear - is not considered a best practice because of condensation - although you can get filters to remove most of the water component- which expensive canned air does not suffer from.)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they only go bad because of electric shocks, corrosion, or heavy memory usage.

You can use a dustblower(the canned kind, not really air tho), soaking the pins in vinegar for a couple of hours, and if corrosion is thick use some baking soda, vinegar and a tooth brush.

Once installed in your system, use +mem86 to check it.

Comment: A DDR module isn't going to go bad because of "heavy memory usage", the module is designed to be used if it failed then it failed because electricity is complicated and electronics fail.  *The failure of electronics have nothing with being used, electronics that are not even used can fail once they are used.*  I had memory modules in working condition in the past, and I unplugged my PC for a week when I plugged it back in two modules had failed.  **I would not suggest putting DDR memory in vinegar.**

Comment: @RamHound hmmm interesting i’ve 4, 4 gigs modules dead because of heavy usage. Drivers started to fail while in use, sound went off and on, etc. Changed the modules and everything went back to normal. About soaking it in water, i meant only the pins or corroded parts, as acid will disolve the salts on the contacts.

Comment: You didn't mention just cleaning the pins, and I still find the fact you suggest using vinegar, as a cleaning solution to be poor advice.  If you want to suggest cleaning the modules, suggest distilled water and Isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: @Ramhound I stand by it, works every time on console catridges. Even though isopropyl alcohol is usually recomended is a powerfull solvent and has to be handled with more care in my opinion. I have taken barnish out off wood by mistake with it. Using vinegar to clean the corrosion and the finish it off with isopropyl acohol would be even better, so no vinegar is left on the ram stick.